# List of available parameters in Deployment & HPA yaml configuration file

Tags: kubernetes, hpa

I am trying to get the list of all the parameters that can be used into Deployment & HPA yaml configuration file. To be more specific, I am looking parameters related to resources i.e. CPU and memory e.g. targetCPUUtilization.

I tried looking the documentation but I don't think that what I found gives all the parameters.
This is what I referred: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/

Would be great if I could get a file where all the parameters are listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you referred to provides a good starting point for understanding the parameters related to resources in Deployment and HPA YAML configuration files. However, it does not provide an exhaustive list of all available parameters.

To get a comprehensive list of all available parameters for Deployment and HPA YAML configuration files, you can refer to the Kubernetes API reference documentation. Here are the links to the relevant sections:

Deployment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/#deployment-v1-apps
Horizontal Pod Autoscaler: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.21/#horizontalpodautoscaler-v1-autoscaling
The documentation is organized into sections for each field in the YAML configuration file, with a detailed description of each parameter and its usage.

Alternatively, you can also refer to the Kubernetes source code to get a complete list of all available parameters. The Kubernetes code is available on GitHub at https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes. The code for the Deployment and **HPA** controllers can be found in the **pkg/controller/deployment** and **pkg/controller/podautoscaler** directories, respectively.

Note that the list of available parameters may vary depending on the Kubernetes version you are using. The links provided above are for Kubernetes version 1.21, but you can select the appropriate version in the documentation to get the parameters relevant to your version.

hope it helps you

Comment: Which file exactly will provide the list under pkg/controller/deployment and pkg/controller/podautoscaler?

Comment: The file that provides the list of controllers under pkg/controller/deployment and pkg/controller/podautoscaler would depend on the specific implementation and codebase you are working with.

Comment: Within each of these directories, there may be multiple files that collectively implement the controller logic. For example, in the Kubernetes controller manager codebase, the Deployment controller is implemented across several files, including deployment_controller.go, deployment_revisions_controller.go, and deployment_strategy_controller.go